# If innerHTML X of a mySQL row then move it to the top of the table

Tags: php, mysql

This PHP code prints out a table from mySQL.
If the row with id "thisone" has innerHTML 2 in it i would like to move that whole row to the top of the table including including username kills and deaths cause they are aligned in the same row.
I think this mySQL print out should be better but well i dont really know how to print stuff propertly this one worked alteast.

Here is how the table looks untouched. As you see it has 1 & 2 in the end. I want all the rows which has team 2 move up to the top.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj2su.png

```html
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "pw", "databasename");
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM online_players";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table id='myTable'>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>username</th>";
                echo "<th>kills</th>";
                echo "<th>deaths</th>";
                echo "<th>team</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['kills'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['deaths'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td id="thisone">" . $row['team'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
 
// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use jQuery:

```js
// read the value
var thisone = $('#thisone');
// check, if value is '2'
if (thisone === parseInt(2)) {
 var player = $(thisone).parent();
  $(player).prepend('#myTable');
}
```

Edit: Can you paste your generated HTML?

Comment: Didnt work something wrong with the code?